# Odoo 16 :File not found

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm trying to create a custom module using odoo 16 , but when I try to activate this custom module it shows me this error "FileNotFoundError: File not found: HelloWorld\views/hello_world.xml"

this is my project structure : [image]

and this is my manifest file where  my module config exists:

```
{
    'name': 'My Custom Module',
    'version': '1.0',
    'summary': 'A custom Odoo module',
    'description': 'Custom module to demonstrate Odoo model creation.',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'author': 'Ahmed',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'data': [
        'views/hello_world.xml',  
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',  
    ],
    'installable':True,
    'auto_install':True,
    'application':True,
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're on Windows and the path is `'views\hello_world.xml'`

Comment: @CZoellner I use Windows and I have been using `/` for the path, and it has been working fine though.

Comment: HTTP and json forward slashes are used.  In windows backslashes are used.  The error is windows and the forward slash is wrong.